# How to add an aggregated variable to an existing dataset in R

Tags: r, aggregate

How do you add a variable to a dataset using the `aggregate` and `by` commands? For example, I have:

```
num x1  
1 1  
1 0  
2 0  
2 0
```

And I'm looking to create a variable to identify every variable for which any `num` is 1, for example:

```
num x1 x2  
1 1 1  
1 0 1  
2 0 0  
2 0 0
```

or

```
num x1 x2  
1 1 TRUE  
1 0 TRUE  
2 0 FALSE  
2 0 FALSE
```

I've tried to use

```
df$x2 <- aggregate(df$x1, by = list(df$num), FUN = sum)
```

But I'm getting an error that says the replacement has a different number of rows than the data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by grouping with 'num' and checking if there are `any` 1 element in 'x'1.  The `ave` from `base R` is convenient for this instead of `aggregate`

```
df1$x2 <- with(df1, ave(x1==1, num, FUN = any))
df1$x2  
#[1] 1 1 0 0
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'num' and create the 'x2' by checking if `any` 'x1' is equal to 1.  It will be a logical vector if we are not wrapping with `as.integer` to convert to binary

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(num) %>%
   mutate(x2 = as.integer(any(x1==1)))
```